# Substr from MySQL by mask (regex)

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a lot of links with params in DB (Mysql 5.7), need to extract id parameter (like this - https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=550585067709, there can be many params, not only one...), have preg_match with regex, which I use in php -

```
preg_match_all('/(?|&)id=(.*?)&/', $link, $matches);
```

How can I extract this id in MySQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
-- output assume a URL of https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=550585067709
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url_col, '?', -1), '&', 1)
FROM dual;

id=550585067709
```

### Demo

Note that the above solution is robust with regards to whether or not there is more than one parameter (i.e. whether or not `&` is present).